# In Eclipse Kepler set smart caret position to be before comments

Tags: java, eclipse, format

In Eclipse Kepler when I press 'Home' on a commented line it moves the cursor to the start of the text.
[image]

Is there a way to move the cursor to before the comments when I click 'Home'?
[image]

**Edit for clarification:**
I don't want to move the cursor to the very beginning of the line. I would like to move it to the beginning of the comment.

Comment: What do you do next? What's your next step when the caret is before ``//``?

Comment: @steffen Next I would delete the line including the `//`. I know I can use `Ctrl + D` to delete the line (which I do) but using `Shift + Home` to select the line and then delete is a habit from other text editors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using OS X with Eclipse Luna, but I found that when I use command + left arrow (probably windows + left arrow in windows) once, I get to the beginning of the comment's text, and when I do the same a second time, it brings me to the beginning of the line, before the forward slashes.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Pressing `Home` once moves to the beginning of the text after the comment and pressing it again moves the cursor to the very beginning of the line regardless of how much white-space there is. 

P.S. `Windows + Arrow` moves the current window's position on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling Smart caret positioning.

[image: Text Editors preference page]

Comment: I tried this before I posted the question but it isn't quite what I'm looking for as it places the cursor at the very start of the line instead of just before the comments. If I were to press `Home` then `Shift + End` followed by `Delete`  to write over the line I would have to `Tab` multiple times to redo the white-space.

Comment: You would only have to repeat the `Tab` key if you had smart indentation disabled.